# How can I access the Criterion function of KI method in `FindThreshold` for a dataset?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data, implementation-details, cluster-analysis

I want to find a threshold for some data set, using Kittler-Illingworth minimum error thresholding method ([KI method](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031320386900300)).  To do so, I use the *Mathematica* built-in function `FindThreshold` with `Method -> "MinimumError"`, which is exactly what I expect.  But, for future uses (e.g. to evaluate a goodness factor for the obtained threshold for a given dataset), I also need the criterion function ($J(t)$) that the method uses to determine the threshold. Is there any way to access the values of this function?

I use *Mathematica 10*, and I should emphasize that here `Dataset` is a set of many points in a (at least) 3D space; it is not an image.